# How fast could Earth spin and sustain life?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, gravity, centrifugal-force, asteroids

When dinosaurs roamed the Earth was the Earth rotating faster creating less gravity to allow for their size? How fast could have the Earth spin and be slowed down by an asteroid to the current rotational speed not completely wiping all life out? 
How much would 100 kg weigh then?

With the asteroid the opposite direction of the Earth's rotation unlike the moon's hard interior that the asteroid would just punch through the crust into the mantle allowing the Earth not to instantly be affected by the change in rotation. Also it was theorized that the moon was a large piece of the Earth liquid mantle removed by an asteroid.

[image]

Comment: An interesting question, but we really do encourage folks to take a stab at the answer before posting.

Comment: Apparently we really still are far from a consensus as to why the dinosaurs were so big. I've studied this a great deal since my dinosaur-crazy daughter was born and her enthusiasm's rubbed off on me. There are several possibilities. The most plausible I have heard is, given the low grade food sauropods had to eat (cycads and pine needles) in the Jurassic, you need to become an industrial scale digestion plant on legs to access economies of scale. The bigger you are, the more efficient this processing, and the upper limit is basically that you get so big that you take so long ....

Comment: ...(about 200 years) to grow up, live  and reproduce, and you thus become too slow to adapt to changing ecologies. Once you have big sauropods and herbivores, it becomes clear why the meat eaters get big. Note that, for modern animals, zoologists have theories they are fairly satisfied with: see [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC64714/) for example.

Comment: The asteroid didn't slow down earth's rotation---it's mostly because of the moon.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix what if it hit was in the opposite direction of the Earth's rotation? I would imagine if the asteroid was big enough and unlike the moon's hard interior that the asteroid would just punch through the crust into the mantle allowing the Earth not to instantly be affected by the change in rotation. Also it was theorized that the moon was a large piece of the Earth liquid mantle removed by an asteroid.

Comment: The asteroid that killed the dinosaurs was the size of a town or city.  The planetoid that formed the moon was comparable in size to mars or the entire earth.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this problem set from Goddard Spaceflight Center](http://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/earth/6Page58.pdf) in the upper Triassic the day was $23.5$ hours.  The rotation speed was then $\frac {24}{23.5} \approx 1.021$ times higher.  The equatorial speed of the earth is now $465.1$ m/sec. The centripetal acceleration at the equator is now $\frac {465.1^2}{6378100}\approx 0.034$ m/sec, which reduces $g$ by $0.3\%$.  In the upper Triassic, the acceleration would only be $4\%$ of that higher, so about $0.035$ m/sec$^2$.  It is not enough to matter.

Comment: The moon was closer too. So twice a day, you would lose some more weight... Also, according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanding_Earth) the earth radius might have been 102% ± 2.8% of today's value. Which would further increase the drop in $g$.

Comment: @Floris: I hadn't seen that,but the Wikipedia page you link to says scientific consensus is against.  Even so, increasing the radius to $102\%$ will decrease $g$ by $4\%$.  That will swamp the decrease due to rotation speed. We still have less than $5\%$ decrease overall.  Not a big effect if you are doing mechanical design of animals.

Comment: We agree - and as for the paleomagnetic data, I'm not sure that "scientific consensus" is against, as much as "the methodology employed has been criticised by the Russian geologist Yuriy Chudinov". The entire "expanding earth" thing is mostly contradicted. But I thought it was worth pointing out that things like this may have occurred, and would have an impact. When did the core stop cooling (think thermal expansion)? How much does an ice age shrink the crust (or a heat wave cause it to grow). Discerning minds want to know.

Comment: @Floris  The moon was once even closer than that:  http://www.aleastory.co.uk/The-Distance-of-the-Moon.pdf

Comment: @JohnForkosh - the expression "how much would 100 kg weigh" is not a blunder: it's a physically accurate expression. 100 kg is a mass (quantity), and on earth it has a weight (force of gravity). Jen uses the term correctly - she asks about the change in the force of gravity on a 100 kg mass.  See for example [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/138296/26969) and [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/137550/26969) for a more detailed discussion of the usage of "mass" and "weight".

Comment: @JohnForkosh it is abundantly clear from the context that the answer to the question "how much does it weigh" should be given in Newton - today, 100 kg weighs 981 N (at certain points on earth). Back then it might have been 978 N or so, according to Ross's answer. I stand by my defense of Jen on this one.

Comment: @JohnForkosh It is rather odd to correct someone by pointing out that kilograms is not a unit of weight, then turn around and say something "weighs 100kg" as an answer. It would profit us more to give a correct answer than to harm your credibility in the name of condescension.

Comment: @JohnForkosh The question was edited yesterday and appeared as having recent activity, so I didn't notice that it was old, sorry. However, discussing how much a mass weighs is not a "blunder" to begin with, so correcting it is unnecessary (to be polite about it). Neophyte or not, the asker has the right units.