# Do you say it right?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, weight

If someone asks you your **WEIGHT** what would you answer in SI Units.

1. My weight is x 'kilogram'
2. My weight is x 'Newton'.

As we know that weight is a force due to local acceleration and still most people say it in kilogram will you correct them or you prefer to stick to the wrong way of saying even after knowing.

Comment: Hence the difference in _customary_ units and _scientific_ units. My weight in customary units is in pounds, stones, kilograms, etc. My weight in scientific units is in pounds-force or Newton.

Comment: "Kilogram force." But this isn't a question about a physics concept.

Comment: Or poundal or dyne but not the slug?

Comment: <blatant self-promotion>I think [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233731/what-is-my-real-weight/233737#233737) provides an adequate answer.</blatant self-promotion>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would answer that:

My mass is 80 kg.

My weight is 784.1 N