# Why are we mentioning weight of the product in kg? Why not Newton?

Tags: mass, terminology, weight

I am confused using this units. Why this changes happened?

Comment: We express the MASS in kg and the WEIGHT in Newton. Sometimes in common language we say that someone weighs $x$ kg but that has nothing to do with the actual definitions of the terms weight and mass.

Comment: Weight=mg where m is Mass and g is acceleration due to gravity. we know F=ma and F is Mentioned in Newton and so why  wight is also mentioned in Newton

Comment: So what it showing in weight machine.  Mass or weight?

Comment: @KanagaSenthilRaja: See [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233731/what-is-my-real-weight/233737#233737).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between weight and mass?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43195/what-is-the-difference-between-weight-and-mass)

Answer (score 1):

The change never happening the lack of distinction between the two words has always been there.
Most people are not Physicists and use the words weight and mass to mean the same thing.
The word mass is hardly ever used in conversation as it is very much a technical word.
This error is reinforced by not using a word like massing instead of weighing and having spring balances calibrated in units of mass.

Comment: It goes even deeper then this. In many places the law defines "kilogram" as a weight, because the word was coined before anyone was making as strong distinction as a matter of course.