# Mass versus Weight

Tags: mass, weight

What are the difference between mass and weight? I keep getting confused in my physics class, and I am in 8th grade. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between weight and mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43195/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mass is a measure of how much matter (atoms) make up an object. Weight is a force that results from that quantity of matter accelerating in a gravitational field. Weight = mass*acceleration due to gravity. Weight can change depending on what gravitational field you are in, mass cannot change.

Comment: Incorrect.  100 atoms of copper do not have same mass as 100 atoms of uranium although both have the same number of atoms.

Comment: Didn't say that mass is the number of atoms. It's an 8th grade level answer to and 8th grade level question.