# Why do physics textbooks mention weight when saying mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, definition, education, weight

I've always found in physics textbooks (and in general too) that when a paragraph or question mentions mass it actually is succeeded by weight of the object in question.

For example,

> *The mass of the man standing on top of the board is 70kg*.

Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43195/2451

Comment: There is no mention of weight in your example.  They say mass and give the value of mass.

Comment: It is because the two are easy to confuse if you live in a constant gravitational field. People talk about weight all the time when they mean mass. Weight is the easiest way to measure mass. You go on a diet to lose mass. But the scale tells you the weight. You buy groceries by weight for the same reason. When I was in high school, I was astonished when my physics teacher told me that a pound is a unit of force. I had always thought it was a unit of mass. I had never heard of the true mass unit, the slug.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not easy to understand, in textbooks it is understood, that on earth the man has a weight of $m*g$ which matters if he moves upward or downward, his mass matters if he moves horizontally.